# Parsing unittest assertions to text file using abstract syntax tree

Tags: python, unit-testing, abstract-syntax-tree

Given a test suite:

```
class MyTestSuite(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_foo(self):
        self.assertLessEqual(temperature, boiling, "boiling will burn the cake")
        self.assertEqual(colour, 'golden brown', "the cake should be cooked until golden brown")

    def test_bar(self):
        self.assertIn('flour', ['flour', 'eggs'], "the flour should be mixed in with the eggs")
```

I would like to produce a text file describing all the assertions and tests. For example:

```
My Test Suite

Test foo:

* temperature <= boiling because boiling will burn the cake
* colour == 'golden brown' because the cake should be cooked until golden brown

Test bar:

* 'flour' in ['flour', 'eggs'] because the flour should be mixed in with the eggs
```

---

## Update

Using `inspect` I have managed to get an iterable list of all the test methods in a module:

```
def __init__(self, module='__main__'):
    if isinstance(module, basestring):
        self.module = __import__(module)
        for part in module.split('.')[1:]:
            self.module = getattr(self.module, part)
    else:
        self.module = module

    self.tests = {}

    for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(self.module):
        if inspect.isclass(obj):
            for method_name in dir(obj):
                method = callable(getattr(obj, method_name))
                if method and re.match('test.*', method_name):
                    spec = ' '.join(re.findall('[A-Za-z][^A-Z_]*(?=_[A-Z])?|[A-Z][^A-Z_]*', obj.__name__)).title()
                    test = ' '.join(re.findall('[A-Za-z][^A-Z_]*(?=_[A-Z])?|[A-Z][^A-Z_]*', method_name)).capitalize()

                    assertions = # a list of strings describing the assertions

                    try:
                        self.tests[spec][test] = assertions
                    except KeyError:
                        self.tests[spec] = {test: assertions}
```

The final step is to extract a list of strings describing the assertions from the test methods. My first solution is to use a load of regexes in conjunction with `inspect.getsourcelines(method)` but there must be less syntax dependent solution. Thanks to Kevin who suggested `ast` as a viable option, but this brings me to a more specific question.

**How can I use `ast` to parse the assertions out of a test method into a human readable format?**

Failing this maybe there are better options?

Comment: Have you tried waving the [ast magic wand](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.parse) over your unit tests?

Answer (score 0):

The doc string for the TestSuite base class says:

> For use, create an instance of TestSuite, then add test case
>   instances. When all tests have been added, the suite can be passed to
>   a test runner, such as TextTestRunner. It will run the individual test
>   cases in the order in which they were added, aggregating the results.
>   When subclassing, do not forget to call the base class constructor.

If you choose to use the TextTestRunner, then you can provide a stream for it to write to:

```
tester = unittest.TextTestRunner( stream=mystream, verbosity=2 )
test = unittest.makeSuite( MyTestSuite )
tester.run( test )
```

Edited to add verbosity = 2; this will print your doc string on each test as it executes.  Is this sufficient information?